# Imageslider reaches the End and goes to nowhere

Tags: javascript, css, image, slider

I have an image slider with 5 images in it. After clicking the button, the slider moves to the next image. When the end is reached it goes to nowhere. My goal is that it shows the first image after the slider is at the end.

```
          <button class="btn">Test</button>
        </div>
      </body>
      <script>
        let button = document.querySelector(".btn");
        let slide = document.querySelector(".s1");
        let slideEl = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
        let move = 0;

        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
          move -= 20;
          console.log(slideEl.length - 1);
          for (var i = 0; i < slideEl.length; i++) {
            slide.style.marginLeft = move + "%";
            if (i >= slideEl.length - 1) {
              console.log(slideEl.length - 1);
              slide.style.marginleft = "100%";
            }
          
          }
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: It looks like you start with marginLeft = 0 yet you set it to 100% at the end.
Try setting it to 0 again. Also mind the capital "L" in marginLeft in your reset statement.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if i use 0 it does not move after i click the button.

Comment: I think your setup is wrong. Without seeing your HTML code I cannot tell for sure but the Javascript is looping through all 5 elements each time you press the button. I am assuming you want to move the image 20% to the left. each click.  
  
In that case use:  
  
`button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        move -= 20;
        console.log(slideEl.length - 1);
        slide.style.marginLeft = move + "%";
        if (move <= -100) {
            console.log(slideEl.length - 1);
            move = 0;
            slide.style.marginLeft = "0";
        }
    });`

Comment: <div class="slidershow middle">
              <div class="slides">
                <div class="slide s1">
                  <img src="1.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="2.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="3.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="4.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                  <img src="5.jpg" alt="" />

Comment: when i do slide.style.marginLeft = "0"; it does not move anymore when i click the button.

Comment: Here are the HTML and CSS https://abload.de/img/cssdqjqk.png https://abload.de/img/html85k5p.png

Comment: I found a solution:    move -= 20;
      console.log(move);
      slide.style.marginLeft = move + "%";
      if (move <= -80) {
        move += 100;
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the console and logged the move element. i saw that it moves -20% on every click. my problem was i targeted the wrong element for that if statement. mikesp gave me a good tip, see above. now when it reaches the end it slides to the beginning.  the last picutre is on -80%. that is the fith image. Also a for loop was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
  move -= 20;
  console.log(move);
  slide.style.marginLeft = move + "%";
  if (move <= -80) {
    move += 100;
  }
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.